# Simple Matrix multiplication takes very long

Tags: matrix, bugs, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

**Bug introduced in 10.1.0 and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

I came across some strange behaviour during a computation involving matrices with symbolic values. It is reproduced below.

Multiplying a random 30x30 array with symbolic values with the identity matrix takes 4 seconds! Converting to a `SparseArray` seems to work, but I don't understand why it should since the matrix size is so small.

*Mathematica* Version is 10.1

```
aa = Table[RandomInteger[10] + Sqrt[RandomInteger[10]]/(1 + 
   Sqrt[RandomInteger[10]]), {30}, {30}];

IdentityMatrix[30].aa; // Timing
```

> `{3.95225, Null}`

```
SparseArray[IdentityMatrix[30]].aa; // Timing
```

> `{0., Null}`

Comment: This has to be a bug ... In 10.0 it is not slow but in 10.1 it is.  I can reproduce it on OS X.  Can you report it to WRI?

Comment: already paying attention to it. I've passed it along to the appropriate tester, etc.

Comment: Quite relevant is [this prior MSE post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65624/a-one-line-proof-that-one-is-zero-using-mathematica-10). It seems someone here (and I mean right here) did not know to leave well enough alone (smack smack).

Comment: Thank you for reporting it. Makes the 3+ hours to narrow it down, worthwhile.

Comment: Bug is still present in version 10.2, Linux

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been fixed as of *Mathematica* 10.3.

```
$Version

(* "10.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)" *)

aa = Table[RandomInteger[10] + 
       Sqrt[RandomInteger[10]]/(1 + Sqrt[RandomInteger[10]]), {30}, {30}];

IdentityMatrix[30].aa; // Timing

(* {0.028025, Null} *)
```