# Behavior of PossibleZeroQ

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I was slightly surprised by the following result:

```
PossibleZeroQ[Gamma[a + b]/Gamma[a] - Pochhammer[a, b]]
(* Out: False *)
```

versus

```
PossibleZeroQ[Gamma[a + b]/Gamma[a] - Pochhammer[a, b] // FunctionExpand]
(* Out: True  *)
```

I had the wrong impression (maybe from the name) that `PossibleZeroQ` would be more likely to err by giving false positives than false negatives. I would think that numerical tests would indeed confirm that these expressions are the same. I guess the problem comes from the poles/zero's of the `Gamma` function. Or should I really be careful with `FunctionExpand` and does it really give possibly false results?

P.S. I came across this in a more practical situation where the equality of two expressions was not easy to see by hand, but simplified it to this core oddity.

Comment: Note that `Gamma[a + b]/Gamma[a] - Pochhammer[a, b] // FunctionExpand` evaluates to `0` before being passed to `PossibleZeroQ`.  So we can probably infer that `PossibleZeroQ` does not use `FunctionExpand` (or `FullSimplify`, which also gives `0` but is mentioned in the docs as being more rigorous). -- It would be nice to get an answer to how `PossibleZeroQ` works, but it might be that its internal workings are known only to WRI.

Comment: Related: [(65624)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65624)

Comment: `#[Gamma[a + b]/Gamma[a] - Pochhammer[a, b]] & /@ {FullSimplify, 
  FunctionExpand}` evaluates to `{0, 0}`.  Note that the `Possible Issues` section of the documentation for `FullSimplify` states "Some of the transformations used by FullSimplify are only generically correct". Similarly, the `Possible Issues` section of the documentation for `FunctionExpand` states "Some transformations used by FunctionExpand are only generically valid". In this case the transformations are not valid when `a` is a nonpositive integer.

Comment: This made me wonder about using `FindInstance`--it doesn't seem like it should be that hard for `FindInstance` to find values at which the two are not the same. E.g., `{Gamma[a + b]/Gamma[a], Pochhammer[a, b]} /. {a -> -2, b -> -3} => {Indeterminate,-(1/60)}`. Yet even if I tell it to just search the integers (`FindInstance[Gamma[a + b]/Gamma[a] != Pochhammer[a, b], {a, b}, Integers]`), it comes up empty: "The methods available to `FindInstance` are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist." [continued....]

Comment: Interestingly, if I instead try FindInstance[Gamma[a + b]/Gamma[a] != Pochhammer[a, b] && a < 0 && b < 0, {a, b}], I get a different warning message ["FindInstance used FunctionExpand to transform the system. Since FunctionExpand transformation rules are only generically correct, the solution set might have been altered."]. If `FunctionExpand` (which makes the two expressions the same: `FunctionExpand[Pochhammer[a, b]] => Gamma[a + b]/Gamma[a]`) was also operating within the uses of FindInstance in the previous comment, it could explain those results as well.